# Wrongly downvoted answer

Tags: discussion

Here:
[PowerSpec G419 Missing Bluetooth?](https://superuser.com/questions/1515208/powerspec-g419-missing-bluetooth?noredirect=1#comment2293126_1515208)

I thought this question to be easily understood (I had no difficulty understanding it) and I am fairly sure my answer was correct and not speculation, and based on experience.

Comment: Your answer is more conjecture based on what appears to be incredibly limited experience. "I got one once and it had it" rather than being reasoned and qualified by any real technical knowledge. I suspect you attract downvotes due to your desire to be the fastest to answer and failing to provide any useful information that might educate the asker on how to do something themselves. "I did and it was fine" is less useful than "I did it, here is how you can do it too."

Comment: I honestly don't care how many of your clients do or don't, it is irrelevant. You gave a vague hand wave at device manager without any information on how to open it, what to do with it or what you are looking for, that is not "how to do it" by any stretch. You use fuzzy language like "Many desktops do not have Wireless" and "Bluetooth is commonly associated with the Wireless adapter." which presumes that people already know why without any explanation and provokes conjecture and the question of "why". Being intentionally vague and using anecdotal evidence does not demonstrate understanding.

Comment: I am thinking differently, yes, but I am also *trying* to help you see what is wrong and how you can improve. If you refuse to accept that people hope you can achieve something better then I guess we're just going to continue with the current status quo.

Comment: @John - You are asking for the reasons you received a downvote, reasonable well thought out reasons with valid explanations, but your response seems to completely give the impression your not willing to even consider the feedback you received.  I have given you similar feedback and in the past, on similar low quality answers, and you either suggest in a comment it’s my feedback is completely wrong or delete the answer.  *The only reason I submitted an answer to this question is because I knew I would receive votes that would prevent the question from being deleted.*

Comment: @John - Your words give the impression we are an annoyance.

Comment: @John - I didn't say you literally said you were annoyed by the community, but the words you use, are giving that impression.

Comment: @John, I'm just a passerby; haven't even looked at the referenced post.  Just wanted to make an observation.  You refer to downvotes indicating that an answer is wrong, which is a bad assumption.  If you hover on the answer downvote button, it offers guidance on what it is appropriate for:  "This answer is not useful".  Being wrong is one possibility, but an answer can be viewed as not useful for many other reasons.  More often than not, answers are downvoted because they are viewed as simply not adding value for one reason or another.  The explanations here suggest that.

Comment: @John Votes are nothing more than anonymous opinions and do not affect rep afaik, I ignore them and only use them when deserved, No research effort, is unclear or not useful, and retract them when this is remedied by the author.

Comment: Excellent observation. +1

Answer (score 8):

> The kind of indiscriminate downvoting I get serves ONLY to beat up, belittle and demean people. It does serve any useful purpose except to drive good people away

I am **absolutely not** the person who downvoted your answer, but your answer doesn't answer a single one of the multiple questions the author actually asked.

Here is a list of the questions the author asked:

- Do all modern desktops not come with Bluetooth support?
- Is one generally expected to buy a Bluetooth adapter if they want Bluetooth on a desktop?
- Am I correct in concluding that it does not?
- Is there a way to use the steam controller's USB adapter as a Bluetooth adapter by any chance?

[image]

You indicate that Bluetooth modules are commonly associated with wireless adapters, which is common on laptops, but I fail to see how it answers any of the author's questions about their desktop.

The `PowerSpec G419` absolutely does not have a Bluetooth module.  If you had pointed this fact out, it's unlikely, your answer would have been downvoted.  You were also given feedback, granted it was under the question, due to the fact you deleting your answer.  That person indicated that due to the author's four different questions the question should be locked and improved before being answered.

> Your post was/is a comment because it was speculation. And the specs
> for the PC (PowerSpec G419) are easily accessible online and there is
> no indication that the PC in question has Bluetooth or a Wi-Fi card
> with Bluetooth mixed in.
>
> This question as off-topic because it is all over the map and utterly unfocused What is the one question here? And your answer could — and still can — be helpful as a comment which you are fully capable of posting with the rep you have.

In conclusion, the [answer](https://superuser.com/posts/1515208/timeline) was submitted within 10 minutes of the question being submitted.  This does not seem to be enough time to submit an answer that was well researched in my opinion.

I personally own a Steam Controller, which comes with an adapter, which will work flawlessly with the controller.  In other words, the Steam Controller comes with its own (USB) adapter.  **Your answer fails to point out this fact and does not answer the real question the author had**

To be clear the author simply wanted to know how to get their Steam Controller to work.  If you had suggested they read the [How to pair to a Wireless USB Receiver](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=6490-QOAJ-7167), indicated the exact steps to get the controller working, the user who downvoted your answer might have voted differently.

It should be pointed out that absolutely nobody here at Super User can reverse the downvote you received only the person who issued it can give you their exact reasoning.  It is also worth pointing out that Super Users Moderators cannot tell you who downvoted your answer.

Comment: As for getting personal comment, I was actually talking about the "we are on totally different pages in life" comment, I am not particularly worried about users who are [removed](https://superuser.com/help/user-was-removed).  I have had hundreds of reputation points lost due to members profiles being destroyed due to being removed.  I don't particularly feel differ that much honestly.

Comment: @John - Making a comment like "being on different pages in life" makes things personal between the two of us, votes are not personal, they are about the contribution.  Furthermore, two users differing on their approaches, has nothing to do with any votes you have received by anyone within the community

Comment: @John - I attempted to reword a few statements, that after reading them, might have sounded like a personal attack.  This answer should only be seen as feedback on the answer you submitted.  I removed my previous commentary due to the current length of this discussion.

Answer (score 3):

### Your answer was not an answer, was — and is — better suited as a comment and that is why I downvoted it.

I am the one who downvoted your answer and clearly told you so — and why — in a now deleted comment. I very clearly stated your answer was not an answer and reads more like a comment so you should have posted it as a comment instead of an answer. Here is the [100% exact comment I made verbatim thanks to Ramhound digging it up for his answer](https://meta.superuser.com/a/13936/167207):

> Your post was/is a comment because it was speculation. And the specs for the PC (PowerSpec G419) are easily accessible online and there is no indication that the PC in question has Bluetooth or a Wi-Fi card with Bluetooth mixed in.
>
> This question as off-topic because it is all over the map and utterly unfocused What is the one question here? And your answer could — and still can — be helpful as a comment which you are fully capable of posting with the rep you have.

Instead of accepting that, you rambled on and on — as you are doing here — about your years of experience and how you are simply right and others are engaging in giving you: “Another drive by downvote for zero reason.”

I attempted to reason with you in the comments there — in the same way others here are attempting to reason with you — but no answer other than 100% submission to your “professional experience” seems to make you happy.

And as others point out, this is not the first time you have posted comments as answers and then get personally outraged if you are downvoted because of that.

So when I finally gave up and said something along the lines of “If you are unhappy with this, please post about it on meta…” which you clearly have done with this post, what is the title of your question?

> “Wrongly downvoted answer”

How ridiculously vain and demanding and tone-deaf that “question” is. We all see our share of “Why was my question/answer downvoted?” posts. But to simply post a tone-deaf answer to a question on the main site, get upset and then just post this “Wrongly downvoted answer” post here is kind of past belief.

I want to respect your supposed years of experience in the computer field, but none of your posts actually reflect that past saying, “Trust me I have done this…” with utterly nothing else to back your posts up that are then followed up with angry indignation if someone even dare question your posts validity.

Look, posting a comment can often be as helpful as posting an answer if the initial question is vague. But in a case like this — where someone is asking about Bluetooth capabilities for [a PC (PowerSpec G419) whose specs clearly indicate there is no Bluetooth](http://powerspec.com/systems/system_specs.phtml?selection=G419) — and you are rambling on and on about generic advice without paying attention to the core reality of this user’s machine, you will be downvoted by me and possibly others.

### This is not personal, but again — and again and again — if you are going to endlessly post low quality answers that are better suited as comments as answers this is what happens.

You taking this stuff personally all the time actually reflects a true lack of experience in your professional skill set. So if you expect people to respect your professional experience, you need to behave in a way that garners that respect. Your current behavior makes me question your supposed professional experience at best.

### And — yet again — you utterly cannot demand people remove downvotes or demand they should remove a comment you don’t agree with.

Yet again, this cycle goes on and on and on…

I disagreed with another of John’s answers, downvoted and added — and as I typed this deleted — a comment to explain and this is the response I received:

> “I think your comment is utterly terrible and incorrect. I said "contiguous segments are good" Nothing wrong with that. I said "using defrag won't change the lifespan much" and that is correct. I said "leave it enabled and on" Nothing wrong with that. My modern X230 is 0% fragmented by leaving it enabled. I think you should remove your comment (straight wrong) and remove your downvote. My advice is from now, not 15 years ago. If you truly believe yourself on this issue, then have the courage to delete my answer.”

Screenshot below for reference.

> [image]

If someone disagrees with an answer, they can downvote it. If someone chooses to, the community *encourages* downvoters to leave an explanation in the comments. That is 100% exactly what I did: Two things this community is designed to do and encourages to do and you seem to narcissistically believe people are “out to get you.” Give it a rest!

You also left this comment after deleting your previous comment:

> “I will remove my comment but I have reported you. I was thoroughly disgusted by your behaviour”

My response was:

> “You mean my behavior where I post a comment — as requested by the community — when a downvote happens? Or my behavior where I have upvoted your answers *when the are good answers* and even have edited them to make your answers look even better?”

Let that soak in: When you post answers that are valid to another member — and the community — you get an upvote and positive attention. You do the opposite? A downvote and — sometimes — a comment explaining why.

Screenshot below for reference.

> [image]

And… John deleted his post [stating the following in a comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1616068/does-defragmentation-increase-lifespan-of-hard-disk-drive/1616070#comment2465080_1616070):

> “I stopped posting Meta months ago and will never return to it. To satisfy you I will delete my answer. You win.”

Screenshot below for reference.

> [image]

I won? What did I win. I downvoted an answer I disagreed with and left a comment. Downvoting is… **not the end of the world**. At no point did I ever want to delete an answer from John, but this community member has decided *one downvote* and *one comment* equates destruction of content.

If the answer is good, my single downvote means nothing. I means that *for now* you have one downvote… And someone can come along and upvote it… And you can even have -1 votes and should still not be upset: If the answer is valid then others will upvote it.

Anyway, as one can see John has stated he will never return to meta. Please already… Please. So ridiculous.

Comment: I have observed the same observations.  However, I have stopped trying to get John to improve their almost technical accurate answers, and now just downvote any answer that isn’t accurate.  I stopped submitting commentary explaining my vote, after this meta question, and after the 10th answer that was deleted due to a single downvote.  It’s always absolutely about the accuracy of the answer.