# Valid answer to question downgraded and deleted with no feedback

Tags: support, feedback

A user answered on my below question and the answer was deleted like it was a wrong answer.

I doubt that is that the spirit of this platform. 
How dogmatic and frustrated has someone to be, to judge so harsh a valid and helpful answer.

[BIOS update Lenovo ThinkPad x1 Carbon 5th](https://superuser.com/questions/1522429/bios-update-lenovo-thinkpad-x1-carbon-5th?noredirect=1#comment2306157_1522429)

Answer (score 8):

The answer was deleted by its owner. If it was "deleted like it was a wrong answer" then it was because the person answering believed it was wrong.

It was then subsequently undeleted, again by the author.

No one else was involved in it's removal or reinstatement.

For the history of that answer see its [timeline](https://superuser.com/posts/1522430/timeline).

Comment: That is strange because the owner was surprised that the answer was downgraded and deleted.

Comment: The owner was surprised it was downvoted, as they [apparently always are](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/13935/wrongly-downvoted-answer), but no one else was involved in its deletion.

Comment: "It looks like it will be downvoted until the reputation added is worthless." - This is incorrect.  The answer received 2 upvotes worth 20 reputation.  It received 2 downvotes worth minus 4 reputation.  The difference between those two values is a positive 16 reputation.  I have noticed a pattern, if you receive feedback on an answer, in most cases you delete your answer.  If you receive even a single downvote you seem to delete your answer.  If you never improve your answers, why is feedback required, and why is the community hostile for not providing it?

Comment: @John people have tried kindly telling you what is wrong to be met with stony silence and a refusal to correct errors, tried to tell you what is wrong and given a downvote only to be met with sullen deletions or "well I think I'm right". After that the only recourse is to downvote and move on as nothing else seems to work. We have also told you what was wrong, as well as why we might like you to stay. Eventually we just run out of carrots and sticks with which to encourage. At some point we can only assume you don't want people to help you improve at all.

Comment: @John - Can you provide specifics of any of those statements that have not been handled by a moderator?  I am positive the moderator team would want to be made aware of unkind statements made to a community user like yourself.  Specifically, I am sure they would want to handle any unkind statements, made to any user of this community.

Answer (score 3):

> A user answered on my below question and the answer was deleted like it was a wrong answer.

The answer has several statements that are incorrect.  The answer indicates that your [`Lenovo ThinkPad x1 Carbon 5th`](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-X-Series-Laptops/X1-Carbon-5th-gen-need-intel-drivers-for-Windows-7/td-p/3637237) does not support Windows 7.  That might not actually be the case, in order to determine that, you would need to indicate what model you have.  **So from the perspective of this community user, the author of the answer, made a statement they don't actually know is the case.**

I personally do not find inaccurate answer to be particularly helpful.  If I read an answer on Super User, I expect for the answer to contained all the required information, to resolve my problem.  I often see incomplete and inaccurate answers to problems I am attempting to solve, and there is nothing more frustrating to read a solution, but for it to be incomplete because it's missing vital information.

Based on my research the ability to run Windows 7 on the `Lenovo ThinkPad x1 Carbon 5th` entirely depends on which processor it has.  `20K4` and `20K3` both support Windows 7 due the fact the processor is not blacklisted within Windows Update. 20HF and 20HR does not support Windows 7 without some additional hacks due to the processor.  However, even if we are talking about 20HF and 20HR, you should still be able to install Windows 7.  However, once installed without some additional work, Windows 7 would be unable to update. **The fact you were unable to even begin the installation process indicates something else was wrong.**

Based on the problems you describe installing pretty much every single operating system you tried, I suspect you attempted to install Windows 7, from a USB 3 device.  By default that wouldn't have worked on any device until you added the USB 3 driver to the Windows 7 ISO.  **As for the problems with the Linux operating system the answer does not even address that problem.**

> How dogmatic and frustrated has someone to be, to judge so harsh a valid and helpful answer.

You might have found the answer helpful.  However, the answer was deleted by the author, it was not deleted by the community. As a member of that community due to the incorrect statements contained within the answer, I didn't actually find the answer helpful.

Here is the truth:  *There is a good chance Windows 7 could actually run on your device.  How easily it is to get Windows 7 running on your laptop entirely depends on the model you actually have.  Based on my research, if you use an older [Intel display driver](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7w9JofZQkxI), it's possible to install it on Windows 7.*

> This is the unfriendly and toxic atmosphere that Stack Employees talk about.

I am going to respond to this commentary.  A downvote because you believe an answer is incorrect, or perhaps more accurately incomplete, is not actually toxic and unfriendly behavior.  **I am a strong believer that incomplete/inaccurate contributions should be improved, instead of simply being removed, and the removing them should be the absolutely last recourse.**

Comment: **I have spent the last 60 minutes researching your device in order to respond to this question, because I think it's important to explain the downvote to the answer your question received, because it certainly isn't because the community is being hostile.**  It is worth pointing out that every single vote I issue is for a legitimate reason.